# How to find the entire solution set for problems where cosine of a quadratic equals the cosine of a linear function?

Tags: trigonometry

I am having an issue when the solution involves a radical that will be undefined if $n$ is less than zero for finding the period.  I am restricted to real numbers. Also because the period is not constant, how can I find the solution for the entire system not just in the principal domain?

The example problem of this type:  $$ \cos(x^2)=\cos(4x-3)$$

From the graph of $\cos(x^2)-\cos(4x-3)$ the period is not constant; how to deal with these situations? 
[image: desmos graph]

Comment: This is the graph of what function?

Comment: thanks, I chose the wrong picture, I will edit to fix it.

Comment: Transform the equation into product of two sines and solve resulting quadratics in general form.

Comment: I have done that but the solution I get only solves for positive solutions because of the issue of the $\Delta < 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\cos A=\cos B$ iff $(A\pm B)/2\pi\in \Bbb Z.$  So $\cos f(x)=\cos g(x)$ iff there exists $n\in \Bbb Z$ such that $f(x)=g(x)+2\pi n$ or $f(x)=-g(x)+2\pi n.$

So in the Q we have $x^2-4x+(3-2\pi n)=0$ or $x^2+4x+(-3-2\pi n)=0$ over all $n\in \Bbb Z.$ The former has solutions in $\Bbb R$ just when $n\ge 0;\;$ the latter when $n\ge 1.$

Answer (score 1):

HINT.-In fact there is no period. But no problem. You can see at your attached figure that there are infinitely many solutions each pair of them are the two solutions of
$$x^2-4x+(2k\pi-3)=0\text{ where } k\in\mathbb Z$$ for a particular value of $k$.